# How can I fix a subquery in a plsql conditional?

Tags: sql, plsql

Currently, inside a loop, I have:

```
    IF(R1.CURRENT_STATE_CODE not in (select stvstat_code from stvstat))
        THEN
        v_cur_state := 'FR';
        ELSE
        v_cur_state := R1.CURRENT_STATE_CODE;
        END IF;
```

This fails because you cannot perform a subquery in a plsql conditional. "subquery not allowed in this context"

How could I accomplish this instead

Comment: Try implementing it as part of the same query which is fetching R1.CURRENT_STATE_CODE with a left outer join on stvstat. Please post the master SQL for better clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set the value in a `select`?

```
select coalesce(max(s.stvstat_code, 'FR'))
into v_cur_state
from stvstat s
where R1.CURRENT_STATE_CODE = s.stvstat_code;
```

This is an aggregation query with no `group by`, so it always returns exactly one row.  If the `where` filters out all rows, then the `MAX()` returns `NULL`.  The `COALESCE()` then fills in a value in that case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding the logic of coalesce(max()).. Do you mind explaining?